# How to get Schema name/database name from Druid ingestion spec json file?

Tags: json, druid

how can I get Schema name/database name from Druid ingestion spec json file.i have gone through the tutorial but didn't find any regarding schema name or database name.

eg:

```
"dataSchema" : {
  "dataSource" : "ingestion-tutorial",
  "parser" : {
    "type" : "string",
    "parseSpec" : {
      "format" : "json",
      "timestampSpec" : {
        "format" : "iso",
        "column" : "ts"
      },
      "dimensionsSpec" : {
        "dimensions": [
          "srcIP",
          { "name" : "srcPort", "type" : "long" },
          { "name" : "dstIP", "type" : "string" },
          { "name" : "dstPort", "type" : "long" },
          { "name" : "protocol", "type" : "string" }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "granularitySpec" : {
    "rollup" : true
  }
}
```

for the above ingestion spec we can get the table name from "dataSource" key and column names from "dimensions" key values. but how to get the schema name or database name? i'am new in Druid and I need to write a parsing application which extracts these details from the json file.
like database name, table name, and column names.any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by schema name or database name?  Datasource is kind of a database for Druid. All the schema fields are listed under 'dimensionsSpec' and 'metricsSpec'. The actual type for dimensions is always String.

Comment: Where these datasources are actually getting stored?

Comment: Segment files are spread across the cluster over history nodes. 
Additional metadata is stored in Mysql or Postrgres databses.

Comment: I tried setting up druid in locale and loaded a son sample data.As attached in the screenshot could see derby being used in "common.runtime.properties" file inside the 'conf' folder.is this the database used for every druid?are segments loaded in to this db?can we specify our own db name?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concept in Druid as "Database" or "Schema". Apache Druid has only "tables"(Datasources) - https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/datasource.html and they are not namespaced in any way.